# python, cx_Oracle, cursor.setinputsizes:'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert many rows to my Oracle database via python, and i follow the answer of this question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881992/python-and-cx-oracle-dynamic-cursor-setinputsizes). However sometimes it dose not work, the codes are like those below:

```
db_types = (d[1] for d in c.description)
c.setinputsizes(*db_types)
```

And when I try to run these codes it always shows such error below:

```
---> 26     db_types = (d[1] for d in c.description)
 27     c.setinputsizes(*db_types)
 28     c.prepare('''INSERT INTO temp 

 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python)

Comment: Well thanks a lot! I find out how to solve this problem at all. It's because a cursor should point to a table at first, and then the cursor's description would be initialized by itself.

Comment: Your use of datatypes in setinputsized helped me, thanks fort he question.